# Displaying an ArrayList on a JSP Page via JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I have a class with a method that returns an ArrayList and I can't get it to display on my JSP page. Here's my code:

```
//java class
public class Confirmation {
ArrayList<Criterion> criterion = null;
ArrayList<String> criterionTitles = null;
EvaluationDefinition eval = null;

public ArrayList<String> getCriterionTitles() {
    criterion = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
    criterionTitles = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < eval.getGroups().get(0).getCriterionCount(); i++ )
    {
       criterion.add(eval.getGroups().get(0).getCriterion().get(i));
       criterionTitles.add(i, criterion.get(i).getTitle());
    }
    return criterionTitles;
}  
}
//jsp page code...
<jsp:useBean id="criterionTitles" scope="page" class="Confirmation" />
// ERROR MSG HERE: Error reading 'criterionTitles' on type Confirmation
<c:forEach var="title" items="${criterionTitles.criterionTitles}">
 <c:out value="${title}" />
</c:forEach>
```

if I run the for loop logic in a servlet and just out.println(criterion.get(i).getTitle() it prints out the titles just fine. It's just when I run the c:foreach loop that I get errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error reading 'criterionTitles' on type Confirmation

Calling `getCriterionTitles()` has thrown an exception. My bet on an `NullPointerException` because `eval` is `null`. Read the server logs for the full stacktrace, trackback the root cause in the code and fix it accordingly.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, putting classes in the default package is a bad idea. It will only work that way on specific servletcontainer/JVM configurations, but not all. In a normal Java class inside a package it's namely impossible to `import` classes from the default package. Some servletcontainers have builtin workarounds for this in order to be "noob-friendly". But you shouldn't rely on that.